# Express handlebars function

Tags: mongodb, express, web, visual-studio-code, handlebars.js

My code:

```
app.engine('hbs', exphbs ({ extname: 'hbs',defaultLayout: 'mainLayout',layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/layout/'}));
```

Error message:

```
TypeError: exphbs is not a function
```

Comment: Did  the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your `TypeError` disappear when you add `exphbs.engine()` like this:

```
const exphbs = require("express-handlebars");

app.engine(
  "hbs",
  exphbs.engine({
    extname: "hbs",
    defaultLayout: "mainLayout",
    layoutsDir: __dirname + "/views",
  })
);
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for helping me.More power!